# how can i register my local jar on skipper server

Tags: skipper

I need some help, I'm starting with Spring Cloud Skipper. I've got a little batch jar made up and I've got the jar on my premises. How do I get it installed on the skipper?
Do I have to tell you where the .jar is in the package intall or can it be done from my project with some properties?
thanks

skipper:>package install --release-name helloworld-local --package-name helloworld --package-version 1.0.0 --properties spec.applicationProperties.server.port=8099
Can not find package 'helloworld', version '1.0.0'
Details of the error have been omitted. You can use the stacktrace command to print the full stacktrace.
skipper:>

Answer (score 2):

I think you are following the [Skipper documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/) and stumbled upon the 3 second tutorial... I did too.

What they missed is to *upload* the package to skipper first

1. Download the hello world zip [here](https://github.com/markpollack/skipper-sample-repository/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/repository/experimental/helloworld/helloworld-1.0.0.zip)
2. Then do this in skipper shell

   ```
    package upload --path /<path_to_the_package>/helloworld-1.0.0.zip
   ```

Then you'll be able to do the install.